# TabView rerender problem with PageTabViewStyle

Tags: swiftui

I found a calendar View here: https://gist.github.com/mecid/f8859ea4bdbd02cf5d440d58e936faec/9169b0293f709bb1f560de2ca8184ea903fd5116

My problem is, that I changed the layout to a tabView with paged behavior:

```
       TabView(selection: $num){
            ForEach(months) { month in
                MonthView(month: month.month, content: self.content)
                    .tag(month.tag)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

The months are generated with this method:

```
private var months: [MonthTabItem] {
    let dates = calendar.generateDates(
        inside: interval,
        matching: DateComponents(day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0)
    )
    var monthtabitems: [MonthTabItem] = .init()
    for i in 0..<dates.count{
        monthtabitems.append(MonthTabItem(id: UUID(), tag: i, month: dates[i]))
    }
    return monthtabitems
}
```

My problem is, that the blue circles gets re-rendered when the paged changes. How can I avoid this?

Will add Video later

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer elsewhere and came to this:

- delete the `id` in the MonthTabItem
- use `id: \.self.month` in the `ForEach`